# How to source files only (no folders) in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

In my gulpfile I'm injecting some files into appcache manifest like this:

```
var cachedFiles = gulp.src('**', {read: false, cwd: 'build'});

gulp.src('src/*.appcache', {base: 'src'})
.pipe($.inject(cachedFiles, {
    addRootSlash: false,
    starttag: '# inject',
    endtag: '# endInject',
    transform: function(path) {
        return path;
    }
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(deployPath));
```

It works, more or less, but also injects folders:

```
# inject
index.html
app  # <-- I don't want this
app/20_main.js
app/filters.js
view  # <-- I don't want this
view/style.css
```

How can I ignore folders themselves, but still include files inside? Googling leads to lots of questions about excluding folders with contents.

Answer (score 0):

The options object passed to `gulp.src` is passed down to [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob), which supports a [`nodir` option](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options):

> - `nodir` Do not match directories, only files. (Note: to match *only* directories, simply put a `/` at the end of the pattern.)

So to exclude folders you can do this:

```
var cachedFiles = gulp.src('**', {read: false, cwd: 'build', nodir: true});
```